# Responsive headers and Magellan's fixed_top option

Tags: zurb-foundation-5, magellan

How do I define different fixed_top values within magellan's options, or css, to accommodate different header heights on various devices? My header height varies from 60px on medium to 120px on large.

The inline nature of Magellan's options trumps all css I use to change this within my media queries.

I have also tried interchange to swap out values to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. Currently there is not really a way to fix this with solely Magellan, for it uses fixed parameters setting the offset. I've applied the following fix:

1. Remove `fixed` from the `data-magellan-expedition` attribute. Magellan will no longer handle the fixed-positioning
2. Add a 'break point' script that adds classes to the `body` which you can use to applied media queries. These break point classes are reusable for other applications as well. An example:

Let's say your html is like:

```html
<div data-magellan-expedition class="your-magellan-nav-bar">
  <div data-magellan-arrival="some-header">
    <a href="#some-header">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- ... -->

<h3 data-magellan-destination="some-header">Some Header</h3>
<a name="some-header></a>
```

Note the missing `fixed` in `data-magellan-expedition="fixed"`.

Now add some JS to your document:

```js
function activateScrollpoints(scrollPoints) {
  var $window = $(window);
  var $body = $(document.body);
  var tId = null;

  function onScroll() {
    var windowScrollTop = $window.scrollTop();

    scrollPoints.forEach(function(point) {
      $body.toggleClass('break-'+point, windowScrollTop >= point);
    });

    tId = setTimeout(function() {
      clearTimeout(tId);
      window.requestAnimationFrame(onScroll);
    }, 100);
  }

  window.requestAnimationFrame(onScroll);
}

activateScrollpoints([310, 500]);
```

The above will add a class `break-310` once the user scrolls more than 310px and another class `break-500` if the user scrolls 310px.

Now in your CSS you could do something like:

```sass
@media #{$medium-up} {
   body.break-310 .your-magellan-nav-bar {
      position: fixed;
      top: 310px; /* Some value for your offset */
      left: 0px;
   }
}

@media #{$small-only} {
   body.break-500 .your-magellan-nav-bar {
      position: fixed;
      top: 500px; /* Some value for your offset */
      left: 0px;
   }
}
```